# Sudoku Generator Algorithm Malfunction

Tags: java, sudoku, variable-declaration

I have a project at school where I have to create a Sudoku Program. I have managed to get a Solver algorithm working but not a Generator. I spent a lot of time online to see if people had found ways to make a working one and I found a man named Mark Fredrick Graves, Jr. (https://www.youtube.com/user/mfgravesjr) who provided a very detailed code on the creation of a sudoku grid on his GitHub (https://github.com/mfgravesjr/finished-projects/tree/master/SudokuGridGenerator). However, I felt that using a one dimensional array was unnecessarily difficult in terms of finding the equations to access lines, columns and boxes. I therefore tried to translate his code into a two dimensional array but I am running into issues with some of his sorting methods and what some variables represent like "int step = (a%2==0? rowOrigin + j: colOrigin + j*9);". What I would like to know is how to translate the methods he uses from one dimensional arrays into two dimensional arrays. Below are the methods (code snippets) in question and my half attempt at translating it myself.

```
public int[] generateGrid(){
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
    solvedGrid = new int[81];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) arr.add(i);

    //loads all boxes with numbers 1 through 9
    for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++){
        if(i%9 == 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(arr);
        }
        int perBox = ((i / 3) % 3) * 9 + ((i % 27) / 9) * 3 + (i / 27) * 27 + (i % 3);
        solvedGrid[perBox] = arr.get(i%9);
    }

    //tracks rows and columns that have been sorted
    boolean[] sorted = new boolean[81];

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        boolean backtrack = false;
        //0 is row, 1 is column
        for(int a = 0; a<2; a++){
            //every number 1-9 that is encountered is registered
            boolean[] registered = new boolean[10]; //index 0 will intentionally be left empty since there are only number 1-9.
            int rowOrigin = i * 9;
            int colOrigin = i;

            ROW_COL: for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                //row/column stepping - making sure numbers are only registered once and marking which cells have been sorted
                int step = (a%2==0? rowOrigin + j: colOrigin + j*9);
                int num = solvedGrid[step];

                if(!registered[num]) {
                    registered[num] = true;
                }else {
                    //if duplicate in row/column
                    //box and adjacent-cell swap (BAS method)
                    //checks for either unregistered and unsorted candidates in same box,
                    //or unregistered and sorted candidates in the adjacent cells
                    for(int y = j; y >= 0; y--){
                        int scan = (a%2==0? i * 9 + y: i + 9 * y);
                        if(solvedGrid[scan] == num){
                            //box stepping
                            for(int z = (a%2==0? (i%3 + 1) * 3: 0); z < 9; z++){
                                if(a%2 == 1 && z%3 <= i%3) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                int boxOrigin = ((scan % 9) / 3) * 3 + (scan / 27) * 27;
                                int boxStep = boxOrigin + (z / 3) * 9 + (z % 3);
                                int boxNum = solvedGrid[boxStep];
                                if((!sorted[scan] && !sorted[boxStep] && !registered[boxNum]) || (sorted[scan] && !registered[boxNum] && (a%2==0? boxStep%9==scan%9: boxStep/9==scan/9))){
                                    solvedGrid[scan] = boxNum;
                                    solvedGrid[boxStep] = num;
                                    registered[boxNum] = true;
                                    continue ROW_COL;
                                }else if(z == 8) { 
                                    //if z == 8, then break statement not reached: no candidates available
                                    //Preferred adjacent swap (PAS)
                                    //Swaps x for y (preference on unregistered numbers), finds occurence of y
                                    //and swaps with z, etc. until an unregistered number has been found
                                    int searchingNo = num;

                                    //noting the location for the blindSwaps to prevent infinite loops.
                                    boolean[] blindSwapIndex = new boolean[81];

                                    //loop of size 18 to prevent infinite loops as well. Max of 18 swaps are possible.
                                    //at the end of this loop, if continue or break statements are not reached, then
                                    //fail-safe is executed called Advance and Backtrack Sort (ABS) which allows the 
                                    //algorithm to continue sorting the next row and column before coming back.
                                    //Somehow, this fail-safe ensures success.
                                    for(int q = 0; q < 18; q++){
                                        SWAP: for(int b = 0; b <= j; b++){
                                            int pacing = (a%2==0? rowOrigin+b: colOrigin+b*9);
                                            if(solvedGrid[pacing] == searchingNo){
                                                int adjacentCell = -1;
                                                int adjacentNo = -1;
                                                int decrement = (a%2==0? 9: 1);

                                                for(int c = 1; c < 3 - (i % 3); c++){
                                                    adjacentCell = pacing + (a%2==0? (c + 1)*9: c + 1);

                                                    //this creates the preference for swapping with unregistered numbers
                                                    if((a%2==0 && adjacentCell >= 81) 
                                                            || (a%2==1 && adjacentCell % 9 == 0)) {
                                                        adjacentCell -= decrement;
                                                    }else {
                                                        adjacentNo = solvedGrid[adjacentCell];
                                                        if(i%3!=0
                                                                || c!=1 
                                                                || blindSwapIndex[adjacentCell]
                                                                || registered[adjacentNo]) {
                                                            adjacentCell -= decrement;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    adjacentNo = solvedGrid[adjacentCell];

                                                    //as long as it hasn't been swapped before, swap it
                                                    if(!blindSwapIndex[adjacentCell]){
                                                        blindSwapIndex[adjacentCell] = true;
                                                        solvedGrid[pacing] = adjacentNo;
                                                        solvedGrid[adjacentCell] = searchingNo;
                                                        searchingNo = adjacentNo;

                                                        if(!registered[adjacentNo]){
                                                            registered[adjacentNo] = true;
                                                            continue ROW_COL;
                                                        }
                                                        break SWAP;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //begin Advance and Backtrack Sort (ABS)
                                    backtrack = true;
                                    break ROW_COL;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(a%2==0) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    sorted[i*9+j] = true; //setting row as sorted
                }
            }else if(!backtrack) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    sorted[i+j*9] = true; //setting column as sorted
                }
            }else {//reseting sorted cells through to the last iteration
                //backtrack = false;

                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    sorted[i*9+j] = false;
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) { 
                    sorted[(i-1)*9+j] = false;
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    sorted[i-1+j*9] = false;
                }

                for(int j = 0; j < 81; j++) {
                    sorted[j] = false;
                }
                i-=2;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!isPerfect(solvedGrid)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: Imperfect grid generated.");
    }

    return solvedGrid;
}
```

My code (unfinished)

```
public int[][] generateGrid(){
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
    solvedGrid = new int[9][9];
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 9; i++) {
        arr.add(i);
        values.add(i);
    }

    //Fill all boxes with number 1 to 9
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if(j == 0) {
                Collections.shuffle(arr);
            }
            solvedGrid[(i/3)*3+(j/3)][(i%3)*3+(j%3)] = arr.get(j);
        }
    }

    //boolean[][] sorted = new boolean[9][9];

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int[] rowColValues = new int[9];
            rowColValues[j] = solvedGrid[0][j];
            ArrayList<Integer> occurence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int k = 0; k < rowColValues.length; k++) {
                occurence.add((k+1), occurence.get(k+1)+1);
                if(occurence.get(k+1) != 1) {
                    //swap with number in the box that isn't already in rowColValues
                    //Not sure how to do this...
                    //Create a method that takes the correct variables as parameters ?
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Read the sudoku row then column wise and swap values that already exist in the column or row.
        }
    }

    print2DGrid(solvedGrid);

    return solvedGrid;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi Max, I would suggest you perform a major editing session on your question. SO users will not go over both the large code snippets you provided in order to tell you how to perform the refactoring I'm assuming you wish to do. Try to port as much of the original solution as you can, and ask for help only on specific places in the code where you feel you have an issue.

Comment: Hi, I hope the modifications have helped you understand a bit more what I want. If you follow the GitHub link and download his word document, you should see more clearly what methods and techniques he uses to generate a valid sudoku grid. I'm simply trying to turn his 1D array code into a 2D array code which is more of a challenge than expected.